# Maven display System.Out in Console

Tags: java, maven, junit

I've written a Testcase in Java (JUnit) and when i'm running the test with maven (mvn test) my System.Out.Println won't display in the console. Is there any solution or is this even possible since I've found nothing in the web.

Comment: Mine does... are you sure you just don't miss them in all other output?

Answer (score 5):

Try running test by:

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.useFile=false
```

Or add this to `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire-version)</version>
    <configuration>
        <useFile>false</useFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

From [the docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#useFile)

> *useFile*:
>
> Option to generate a file test report or just output the test report
>   to the console.
>
> Type: boolean
>
> Required: No
>
> User Property: surefire.useFile
>
> Default: true